# Why nbtstat -A ip , returns "host not found" in win10 virtualbox and on server 2003 it returns remote machine name table?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, netbios

[image]

---

[image]
How to get nbtstat -A ip to return remote machine name table on win10?

Both(not running at the same time) have in virtualbox network adapter "Bridget adapter"

On win 10(firewall disabled):

With TCP/IP > WINS > Enable NetBIOS: after entering the command nbtstat -A "ip" it takes 5 secconds for "host not found" to appear.

With TCP/IP > WINS > Disable NetBIOS: after command nbtstat -A "ip", "host not found" appears instantly.

(I am not interested in it to work in virtualbox, I am using that for troubleshooting, on the main PC with win10 its the same issue)

(not interested in using nbtstat -A output, it is for a game that does networking over netbios, on win10 when I attempt to host or be guest I get a crash with error "Network initialization failed, all game slots used!"; in server 2003, the game does not crash with error, it works and nbtstat -A ip returns remote machine name table; then tested on server 2003 with netbios disabled in TCP/IP, nbtstat -A ip returns "host not found" and with the game I will now get the crash error as with win10)

Later I did a Network reset from windows settings and enabled smb1, and now it shows that it is master browser, but nbtstat -A "ip" "host not found"

[image]

Comment: You need to come up with a clear question rather than an array of observations and sharing thins you do not want, or you run the risk of this question being closed.